# AES 128 CBC Encryption Not working in Go but working in Node.js

Tags: node.js, go, encryption, aes

I'm trying to port some Node.js code that I've written a while ago, and I cannot get it to work in Go for some reason.
The weird thing is that my Go code will work with some inputs (e.g. `exampleplaintext that is longer than a single block and some pad`)

When I put a payload that does not work in Go, I'll get a `panic: crypto/cipher: input not full blocks` error.

I know I'm definetly doing something wrong here, but since I'm fairly new with Go I'm not able to pinpoint the issue by myself.

Node.js Code:

```
const crypto = require("crypto")


var AESKey = Buffer.from("Ua\x1E4\x0E[\x0FH\x13\r\x1CWdKY*").toJSON().data
var aesKeyBytes = new Uint8Array(AESKey)

let cipherIV = crypto.randomBytes(16);
let cipher = crypto.createCipheriv("aes-128-cbc", aesKeyBytes, cipherIV)
let encrypted = cipher.update(Buffer.from("this is a test for so"), "utf8", "binary")
encrypted += cipher.final("binary")

console.log(Buffer.from(encrypted).toString("base64"))
```

Go:

```
AESPrivateKey := []byte("Ua\x1E4\x0E[\x0FH\x13\r\x1CWdKY*")

plaintext := "this is a test for so"
block, _ := aes.NewCipher(AESPrivateKey)
mode := cipher.NewCBCEncrypter(block, []byte("TestingIV1234567"))

mode.CryptBlocks([]byte(plaintext), []byte(plaintext))
fmt.Println(base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString([]byte(plaintext)))
```

Comment: I'm not Go expert, but this looks troublesome to me: `mode.CryptBlocks([]byte(plaintext), []byte(plaintext))`  AES-CBC will generate a number of ciphertext bytes that is the smallest multiple of the encryption block size (16) that is strictly larger than the number of bytes of plaintext being encrypted.

Comment: A block cipher mode like CBC requires padding of the plaintext. In the NodeJS code this is done *automatically*, in the Go code it's not and thus must be *explicitly* implemented. Here you can find a Go implementation for PKCS#7 padding used in the NodeJS code: [pkcs7pad](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/zenazn/pkcs7pad).

Comment: Also, there are nice examples for each AES mode in the docs for the `cipher` package. https://pkg.go.dev/crypto/cipher@go1.18.1#example-NewCBCDecrypter

Comment: Looks like I was indeed missing `PKCS#7` padding from my code, the implementation suggested by @Topaco worked.